# Extract data from Wikidata using PHP

Tags: php, wikipedia, wikidata, wikidata-api, wikidata-query-service

I have used Faker to generate persons and I want to do the same thing using Wikidata. By getting names, date of birth, gender, first paragraph and other specified similar data. In addition being able to avoid duplicates by checking existing persons (e.g Q4926) I have fetched before. Wikidata Query = https://w.wiki/5LUr

Is it possible to use [freearhey/wikidata](https://github.com/freearhey/wikidata) or [addwiki/wikibase-api](https://github.com/addwiki/wikibase-api) or should [query.wikidata.org/sparql](https://query.wikidata.org/sparql) be used diretly

Code snippet currently used

```
if ($s == 'generate_fake_users') {
    require "assets/libraries/fake-users/vendor/autoload.php";
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
    if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $_POST['password'] = '123456789';
    }
    $count_users = $_POST['count_users'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $avatar = $_POST['avatar'];
    ob_end_clean();
        header("Content-Encoding: none");
        header("Connection: close");
        ignore_user_abort();
        ob_start();
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status' => 200
        ));
        $size = ob_get_length();
        header("Content-Length: $size");
        ob_end_flush();
        flush();
        session_write_close();
        if (is_callable('fastcgi_finish_request')) {
            fastcgi_finish_request();
        }
    for ($i=0; $i < $count_users; $i++) { 
        $genders = array_keys($wo['genders']);
        $random_keys = array_rand($genders, 1);
        $gender = array_rand(array("male", "female"), 1);
        $gender = $genders[$random_keys];
        $re_data  = array(
            'email' => Site_Secure(str_replace(".", "_", $faker->userName) . '_' . rand(111, 999) . "@domain.com", 0),
            'username' => Site_Secure($faker->userName . '_' . rand(111, 999), 0),
            'password' => Site_Secure($password, 0),
            'email_code' => Site_Secure(md5($faker->userName . '_' . rand(111, 999)), 0),
            'src' => 'Fake',
            'gender' => Site_Secure($gender),
            'lastseen' => time(),
            'active' => 1,
            'first_name' => $faker->firstName($gender),
            'last_name' => $faker->lastName
        );
        if ($avatar == 1) {
            $urls = array("http://lorempixel.com/".$wo['profile_picture_width_crop']."/".$wo['profile_picture_height_crop']."/people","https://placeimg.com/".$wo['profile_picture_width_crop']."/".$wo['profile_picture_height_crop']."/people");
            $rand = rand(0,1);
            $url = $urls[$rand];
            $a = Site_ImportImageFromFile($url,'_url_image','avatar');
            if (!empty($a)) {
                $re_data['avatar'] = $a;
            }
        }
        $add_user = Site_RegisterUser($re_data);
    }
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: “Is it possible” to use one of those three libraries? I don’t see why not? Did you try?

Comment: Wikidata does not have "first paragraph" - you would need to use the Wikipedia API for that.